# Wrong facebook page post url used with error "An access token is required to request this resource."

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting unexpected behavior from facebook graph api. I am posting on behalf of a page via cURL and the posts appear on the page, however the link format shows a facebook url e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/507522299329185/feed, instead of the actual website link which was supplied, e.g. http://ameboapp.com/2fh2s...

This is the function used to post with a page access token.

```
public function postLink($title, $url, $caption, $description, $message, $image_url) {

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/' . $this->page_id . '/feed';

    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'access_token' => $this->page_token,
        'link' => $url,
        'picture' => $image_url,
        'name' => $title,
        'caption' => $caption,
        'description' => $description,
        'message' => $message,
    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    return $response;
}
```

On visiting the graph link, this error is displayed ""An access token is required to request this resource."

Can anyone help discern what is going on and how to fix? Thanks. Actual page is here : https://www.facebook.com/ameboapp

Comment: Sounds like $this->page_token is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$url` to the Graph API call:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/' . $this->page_id . '/feed';
```

but you're also using that same variable in the post:

```
'link' => $url,
```

You should have a second URL, the one you want in the post, for `'link'`. Right now you're just posting the API call as the link for the post, which'll never work.